# How to add a number (date) to the left of an element in Boostrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Bootstrap** and I would like to add a number (date) to the left of each element on a list **that covers both lines of code**. I would also like it to be styled like in the next image: (square border and red number)

[image]

I'm using a normal list:

```
<h2>My Calendar:</h2>    
  <ul>
    <li>09/20/2015: Kate's birthday</li>
         <p>Kate is my girlfriend and this day is her birthday.</p>
    <li>09/23/2015: My birthday</li>
         <p>This day I will be 20 years old.</p>
    <li>09/27/2015: John's birthday</li>
         <p>John is my best friend and his party will be great.</p>
  </ul>
```

I have tried several things with no success :( Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: `have tried several things` - exactly *what* have you tried?

Comment: Well, the most important one was putting the number inside a div with a border but I couldn't make it to cover 2 lines, just one... That's basically my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use positioning to create the date to cover the two lines. Here I have added a `span` element to contain the date in order to achieve this:

<sup>As a note, in order to follow correct markup, I have also moved your `p` tags to within your li elements, as they aren't actually valid otherwise.</sup>

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 80px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
li span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 20px;
}
li p {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<h2>My Calendar:</h2> 
<ul>
  <li><span>09/20/2015:</span> Kate's birthday
    <p>Kate is my girlfriend and today is her birthday.</p>
  </li>
  <li><span>09/23/2015:</span> My birthday
    <p>This day I will be 20 years old.</p>
  </li>
  <li><span>09/27/2015:</span> John's birthday
    <p>John is my best friend and his party will be great.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is perfect sir! I think the mistake was not putting the <p> inside my <li>... Thank you SO much!!

Comment: I forgot to ask sorry, how do you include that code snippet on your answer? I'm new here :P

Comment: no problem @AlejandroArdavín! You can press `Ctrl` + `M` or when you're in the editor there's a button at the top for code snippet (looks a bit like a new page icon with `</>` on it)!